# Java stream, how to GROUP BY and find product of stream

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have this stream where I get the "daily return" of each balance in the stream, but I want to get the product of all daily returns for each accountId. I know I need to put something like:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n.getAccountId(), Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::multiply)));
```

in, but I'm not sure how. Here is the stream so far:

```
Map<Long, Double> solution = new HashMap<Long, Double>();

balances.stream()
          .forEach(n -> {
              if(n.getCashflow().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                  solution.put(n.getAccountId(), n.getEndingBalance().divide((n.getStartingBalance().add(n.getCashflow())), 6, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue());
              }
              else {
                  solution.put(n.getAccountId(), (n.getEndingBalance().subtract(n.getCashflow())).divide(n.getStartingBalance(), 6, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue());
              }
              });
```

Please feel free to suggest any way to get to this solution, and thank you!

Comment: `Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::multiply)` you do understand this will always produce zero right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to follow, let's separate the computation of daily return from the stream:

```
Function<Balance, BigDecimal> dailyReturn = n -> {
    if (...) {  
        return ...;
    } else {
        return ...;
    }
};   // or use a ternary statement
```

Now we can collect a product of all daily returns for each account using the 3-argument `toMap` collector:

```
balances.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Balance::getAccountId, 
    dailyReturn, 
    BigDecimal::multiply
));
```

Comment: I wrote it out, but I was having trouble because solution needs to be Map<Long, Double>.

Comment: Define `dailyReturn` as `Function<Balance,Double>` and use `(a,b) -> a*b` as the third argument to `toMap`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Balance {

  private Long accountId;
  private BigDecimal cashflow;
  private BigDecimal startingBalance;
  private BigDecimal endingBalance;
}

List<Balance> balances = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Long, Double> solution2 = balances.stream().map(n -> {
    BigDecimal bd;
    if (n.getCashflow().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
        bd = n.getEndingBalance()
            .divide(n.getStartingBalance().add(n.getCashflow()), 
                            6, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    } else {
        bd = (n.getEndingBalance().subtract(n.getCashflow()))
                .divide(n.getStartingBalance(), 6,
                    RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    }
    return new SimpleEntry<Long, Double>(n.getAccountId(), bd.doubleValue());
}).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.reducing(1d, Entry::getValue, (d1, d2) -> d1 * d2)));

System.out.println(solution2);
```